# How to get respected column data with count(*)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table which gives count of rows on selected condtion from database table in view
like this.

The table data 3 in bellow are count of rows on condition of 'a' and 'e'.

Like bellow query

```
    select count(*) from table1 where col1="a" and col2="e";
```

When I click on 3 I want to get all 3 id's and count as 3 with out put as single row

Bellow, I want id's 1,5,7 on click table data 3

```
                 #  | a | b | c | d |   
                ----|---|---|---|---|---
                 e  | 3 |   |   |   |   
                ----|---|---|---|---|---
                 f  |   | 0 | 1 |   |   
                ----|---|---|---|---|---
                 g  |   |   |   |   |   
                ----|---|---|---|---|---
```

My database table is

```
                id |col1 |col2|
                 1 |  a  | e  |
                 2 |  b  | g  |
                 3 |  a  | f  |
                 4 |  c  | f  |
                 5 |  a  | e  |
                 6 |  b  | f  |
                 7 |  a  | e  |
```

I want id's with count

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. What query have your tried? Where is "12" displayed in the question? are you referring to the 12 "cells" of the displayed matrix?

Comment: sorry that is 3

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking how to form a query when a user clicks on the 3? If so is this for PHP? (if something else; what is it?) What have you attempted to solve your problem? SO is not a free coding service (as stated before). You are expected to try first.

Comment: I tried, i am not getting idea how to get those respected rows on the conditions to show those rows  in another page. And i am using php codeigniter

Comment: *i am using php codeigniter* then add these as topics to your questions

Comment: the query that gets executed on click of 3 has to pass parameter "a" (from column, and "e" from the row. the query will then look like `select id from table where col1=&columnparameter and col2=&rowparameter` but you need to supply the PHP that you are using to display the matrix. I'm not an active PHP coder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i got your problem correctly.   I think your looking for something like :

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM table1 WHERE col1 = 'a' and col2 = 'e'`;

Comment: yes like this only, but how to fetch each one in program

Comment: So, you do not want to make a server call on the click of 3 (or other values) 
 and want serve the values from GUI only?

Comment: I have to pass these id's to server and get information of those in another page

Answer (score 0):

Use query as:
SELECT id,count(*) as countRow FROM table1 WHERE col1="a" AND col2="e"